# Поиск использования переменных в VS, но только write access

Tags: visual-studio

Есть Find Usages, это понятно.
Но в том же Eclipse есть Search > Write Access / Read Access.
Можно ли такое же провернуть в студии? Или в том же Resharper?

Comment: Если речь идёт о проектах .Net, то в Resharper вроде была такая возможность. В самой студии нет.

Comment: Да, что-то не могу найти. Но это, конечно, ахтунг. Как всякую ерунду сделать, типа ч/б иконки, тёмная тема, заглавные буквы в меню - это пожалуйста, ускорит разработку до не описуемых высот...

Comment: 2015 версию ещё не выпустили, возможно там появится. Обычно полезные фичи из сторонних утилит потом появляются и в студии.

Comment: есть [вот такой](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) форум. Можно написать им, возможно шансы увидеть эту фичу возрастут.

Comment: Можно поставить data breakpoint и найти, где переменная изменяется. А вообще, в нормальной программе, любой доступ к переменной локализован в нескольких местах и таких потребностей возникать не должно.

Comment: Э, не согласен, что если такой опции нет, то это вам не нужно. Всё таки в эклипсе в явовском проекте иногда пользовался.

Comment: Обновил первый пост

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В окне Find Results можно задать фильтр:
[image: Usages of > Filter > Show Read/Write Usages]

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный студийный Find References не делает различия между вызовами геттеров и сеттеров. Как и остальные стандартные инструменты - Call Hierarchy и Code Map.

Все они используют термин "вызова" (call) - а вызов всегда происходит из того места, где свойство упоминается в коде.

То, что приведено на скриншоте - это функционал Resharper.

Можно попробовать оставить заявку на фичу на [Uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/), но, судя по висящему там уже 4 года ["сделайте go to implementation"](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2248038-new-vs-option-go-to-definition-implementation), шансы на пропихивание фичи по навигации в коде - почти никакие.